# Listen for custom event only once in Vue.js single file component

Tags: vue.js

I see that Vue allows listening to a custom event only once using [`vm.$once( event, callback )`](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-once) but is there a way this can be done in a single file component?

Currently we're using the following way of listening to emitted events in the components.

```
events: {
   'Event-Name': function () {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`vm.$off()`](https://vuejs.org/api/#vm-off) view model method to remove the event listener:

e.g.

```
events: {
    Event-Name: function () {
        ... // whatever logic your event needs to do
        this.$off('Event-Name')
    }
}
```